# Analytical solution for coupled heat equations with convective term

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The equations for (non-equilibrium) convective heat transfer between a fluid and a solid are

$$\frac{\partial T_f}{\partial t}=-v\frac{\partial T_f}{\partial x}+g(T_s-T_f)$$
$$\frac{\partial T_s}{\partial t}=h(T_f-T_s)$$

Evaluated on the spatial doman $[0,L]$. With initial and BCs
$$T_f(x,0)=T_s(x,0)=T_0$$
$$T_f(0,t)=T_{in}$$

To solve these coupled equations, would one need to take a Fourier transform of both equations? If yes, what would be the next step?

Edit: deleted last BC

Comment: You have four boundary conditions to impose, and a problem which admits only three conditions. Something was left over.

Comment: Yes, my bad. The last condition should not be there.